# making pretty ebooks using LaTeX

Tags: templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preparing PDF files for ebook readers, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/preparing-pdf-files-for-ebook-readers-etc)

I want to make a pretty ebook using LaTeX. I was wondering if somebody help me to find some sample files or templates to do this on the Internet or to introduce me helpful packages.

Comment: Related questions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/preparing-pdf-files-for-ebook-readers-etc) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub)

Comment: Or, you could use a human-friendly format (say, markdown) for your source, and use, say, [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert it to desired format(s) from that.