# Is there a document class optimized for small screens (i.e. phone screens)

Tags: document-classes, ebook, screen

I happen to read more documents on my (android) phone, including scientific papers from the arXiv (where the TeX source is available). Obviously, such a narrow screen is not well suited to read papers made with the usual \documentclasses .

What is the best way to compile a LaTeX document in order to read it easily on a small screen (smart phone or e-book reader) ?

Comment: Related questions : [Preparing PDF files for ebook readers, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3070/1913) and [LaTeX options for Kindle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1632/1913)

Comment: This template for iPhone screens doesn't quite answer your question because you seem to be looking for a more general solution, but it think it's nonetheless of interest for this question: [http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=765](http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=765)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can specify your own paper size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={<width>,<height>},margin=5mm}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. With [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2897v1) arXiv paper, tweaking the document class to remove some options and using `\geometry{papersize={64.96 mm,48.72 mm}, margin=2mm}` I have something which works, except for the abstract and long eguations, which dispears on the side of the page :-( I'll try some more tweaking with the geometry package.

Comment: you can decrease the size of such formulas or using the several existing math environments from amsmath which allow line breaking

Comment: I want to slightly change already written documents, not to look manually for the problematic equations and so on. A short modification of the preamble with \usepackage{geometry} is what I need. I've finally solved the "long equations problem" by providing a large page with a narrow text, the right margin giving the space for the equations, attained with an occasionnal scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

There's a discussion about that topic including some suggestions/workarounds at http://mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=57861

One option could be to use the [Memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) package, which offers an ebook option for the paper size.