# Calculating right angle triangle side inside LaTeX

Tags: calculations

I'd like compute the width of a screen from it's diagonal and its aspect ratio inside a LaTeX document. The formula is easy to get from the Pythagorean theorem, but needs square roots.

I currently compute this using the `calc` package to compute the square root with the [Babylonian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method), but it is not very elegant. What is the best way to compute square roots (and other functions) inside latex ?

Comment: What is your desired accuracy?

Comment: For my application (display) a 1% is enough.

Comment: édéric 1% is generally ok; the only problem is : what is the amplitude of the lengths ? 1pt .. 5m The next problem is : Do you need a fast code ?

Comment: @Altermundus : My current application is [to convert a document for a phone screen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14420/1913), so the diagonal length would be around 15 cm. So the precision and speed are not crucial. But I can easily imagine situations where the size is bigger (in the order of 1 m, for scale 1:1 representation of a screen capture on a poster) and wher th need for speed would be more important ([batch conversion of arXiv documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1632/1913)). And, of course, I feel that using a sub-optimal solution with TeX would be an oxymoron.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is  an interesting question. First we need to compare and analyse some answers

1) With Lua : This is the future and it's very accurate but  unfortunately it's not enough used and  a lot of TeX's users works only with pdf(la)TeX.

2) `fp` solution is fine but we need to use it with precaution because this can be slow. It's the method that I prefer.
But a problem can arrive with `fp` if you need to get the result of `(-1.5)^(2)`.

The next code is  from Christian Tellechea 2009  modified by me.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fp}   
\makeatletter  
\def\FP@pow#1#2#3{%
 \FP@beginmessage{POW}%
 {\def\FP@beginmessage##1{}%
 \def\FP@endmessage##1{}%
 \FPifzero{#2}%
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
 \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
 \fi
 {\FP@pow@zero{#3}}%
 {\FPifint{#3}%
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
 \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
 \fi  
{\FPifneg{#2}%
 \FPneg\FP@tmpd{#2}%
 \FPln\FP@tmpd\FP@tmpd
 \FPmul\FP@tmpd\FP@tmpd{#3}%
 \FPexp\FP@tmpd\FP@tmpd
 \FPtrunc\FP@tmp{#3}0%
 \ifodd\FP@tmp
     \FPneg\FP@tmp\FP@tmpd
 \else
     \let\FP@tmp\FP@tmpd
 \fi
\else
 \FPln\FP@tmpd{#2}%
 \FPmul\FP@tmpd\FP@tmpd{#3}%
 \FPexp\FP@tmp\FP@tmpd
\fi
}% 
{\FPln\FP@tmpd{#2}%
 \FPmul\FP@tmpd\FP@tmpd{#3}%
 \FPexp\FP@tmp\FP@tmpd}%
}%
\global\let\FP@tmp\FP@tmp}%
\FP@endmessage{}%
\let#1\FP@tmp}    
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\FPpow\temp{-1.5}{2}
\temp 

\FPpow\temp{-2}{3}
\temp 
\end{document}
```

3) `pgfmath` . The Martin's answer describes the traditional method. It can also be slow and sometimes inaccurate for extreme values. The next picture is to illustrate inaccurate results sometimes with `pgfmath`. The picture comes from the pgfmanual in the paragraph *The Syntax of Projection Modifiers*. The intersections of the three altitudes are fine with small sizes but with a big zoom we get this :

[image]

4) with `fpu`. It's possible to use `fpu` It's a package inside `pgf`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}   
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newlength{\lengtha}
\newlength{\lengthb}  
\begin{document} 

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed} 
\setlength{\lengtha}{1pt}
\setlength{\lengthb}{1pt}
\pgfmathparse{sqrt(\lengtha*\lengtha + \lengthb*\lengthb)}
\pgfmathresult 
\end{document}
```

The result is  1.414192000000000. This strange because `pgfmath` in this case gives 1.41421 while `fp` with the same values gives 1.414213562373095042.

5) `\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}`  Another possibility is the `fixed point arithmetic`. It's  again inside `pgf`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}   
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic} 
\newlength{\lengtha}
\newlength{\lengthb}  
\begin{document}      
\setlength{\lengtha}{1pt}
\setlength{\lengthb}{1pt}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fixed point arithmetic={scale results=10^-6}} 
\pgfmathparse{sqrt(\lengtha*\lengtha + \lengthb*\lengthb)}
\pgfmathresult  
\end{document}
```

The result is as with `fp`, it's normal `fp` is used !!  result =  1.414213562373095042

6) `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`  When you need to calculate the distance between two nodes, you can use a macro that I define in my package: `tkz-euclide`. It's a mix  with `fp`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (3,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,4);

 \tkzCalcLength[cm](A,B) 

 \node {\tkzLengthResult } ;
\draw (A) circle (\tkzLengthResult cm) ;
\draw[fill=red] (A) circle (2pt) ; 
\draw[fill=red] (B) circle (2pt) ;  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`\tkzLengthResult` gives 5.00000 There is an option to get the result in pt or in cm.

7)   Finally the last solution used `TeX`. This solution has been written by a friend J_C Charpentier. This is interesting. The macro is named `\pythagore` and this macro uses another macro `\SQRT`to get the square root of an integer < 1962446671 .

```
\documentclass{article}    
\makeatletter
\newcount\@tempcntc
\newcommand\SQRT[2]{%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % #2 = \sqrt{#1} (valeur entière)    %
  % #2 est une longueur                %
  % #1 ne doit pas dépasser 1962446671 %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % Initialisations
  \@tempcnta #1\relax % Sauvegarde valeur
  \@tempcntb 1 % juste pour le premier test
  \@tempcntc #1\relax % Terme en cours
  % simili racine pour le premier terme !!!!
  \ifnum \@tempcntc > 1073741824 % 2^{30}
    \divide \@tempcntc 32738
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 268435456 % 2^{28}
    \divide \@tempcntc 16384
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 67108864 % 2^{26}
    \divide \@tempcntc 8192
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 16777216 % 2^{24}
    \divide \@tempcntc 4096
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 4194304 % 2^{22}
    \divide \@tempcntc 2048
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 1048576 % 2^{20}
    \divide \@tempcntc 1024
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 262144 % 2^{18}
    \divide \@tempcntc 512
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 65536 % 2^{16}
    \divide \@tempcntc 256
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 16384 % 2^{14}
    \divide \@tempcntc 128
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 4096 % 2^{12}
    \divide \@tempcntc 64
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 1024 % 2^{10}
    \divide \@tempcntc 32
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 256 % 2^{8}
    \divide \@tempcntc 16
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 64 % 2^{6}
    \divide \@tempcntc 8
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 16 % 2^{4}
    \divide \@tempcntc 4
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 4 % 2^{2}
    \divide \@tempcntc 2
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 2 % 2^{1}
    % c'est 3 ou 4, l'arrondi est toujours 2
    \@tempcntc 2
    \@tempcntb 0 % pas de boucle !
  \else\ifnum \@tempcntc > 1
    % C'est 2, l'arrondi est 1
    \@tempcntc 1
    \@tempcntb 0 % pas de boucle !
  \else
    % c'est 0 ou 1 la racine est le nombre
    \@tempcntb 0 % pas de boucle !
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi % joli !
  % Boucle principale (Newton)
  \loop
  \ifnum\@tempcntb>0
    % Calcul du terme suivant
    \@tempcntb \@tempcnta
    \divide \@tempcntb \@tempcntc
    \advance \@tempcntc \@tempcntb
    \divide \@tempcntc 2
    % On regarde où on en est
    % (différence entre l'itération au carré et le nombre initial)
    \@tempcntb \@tempcntc
    \multiply \@tempcntb \@tempcntb
    \advance \@tempcntb -\@tempcnta
  \repeat
  % Sauvegarde du résultat
  #2\the\@tempcntc sp\relax
}
\newcommand*\pythagore[3]{%
  \dimen0=#1\relax
  \@tempcnta \dimen0
  \dimen0=#2\relax
  \@tempcntb \dimen0
  % Pour éviter les débordements
  % on travaille en 1/32 de point
  \divide \@tempcnta 2048
  \divide \@tempcntb 2048
  % calcul de a*a+b*b
  \multiply \@tempcnta \@tempcnta
  \multiply \@tempcntb \@tempcntb
  \advance \@tempcnta \@tempcntb
  % appel de la racine
  \SQRT{\the\@tempcnta}{#3}%
  % Fin des débordements !
  #3 2048#3\relax
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\result}        
\begin{document} 

\pythagore{2pt}{2pt}{\result}
\the\result 

\pythagore{3pt}{4pt}{\result} 
\the\result

\pythagore{6pt}{8pt}{\result} 
\the\result 
\end{document}
```

Results are :  2.8125pt ;  5.0 pt and 10.0pt

Answer (score 14):

I would use `fp`'s power function for square roots and the like. With `fp`'s accuracy you will also minimize round off errors to near 15 decimal places.

Consider the square root of 10. You write it as a power function:

```
\FPpow\temp{10}{0.5}
```

We get 3.162277660168379312

You access the value in the macro `\temp` (it can be any name, `fp` will define it on the fly).

Translating this back to a power of two we get:

```
 \FPpow\temp{\temp}{2}
 \FPround\temp{\temp}{15}
 \temp

 10.000000000000000
```

Minimal shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\FPpow\temp{10}{0.5}
\temp

\FPpow\temp{\temp}{2}
\FPround\temp{\temp}{15}
\temp
\end{document}
```

The `\temp` variable used accumulates the results. No need to clutter the namespace.

Comment: @Yannis : The problem with fp and \FPpow arrives with `\FPpow\temp{-2}{2}`. With lengths (positive values) is not a problem but the problem exists ! I modified my answer to give a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Altermundus If one expects negative values in the input then upstream checks are essential eg, `\FPpow\temp{-1}{0.5}`!

Comment: yes you are right with .5 but if the  exponent is an integer it's damage to get an error (  with a polynomial function for example)

Comment: I don't see how that can be considered a continuation. If it needs to be analogized, it's acting like an accumulator.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the math capabilities of the vector graphics package [`PGF`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\diagonal}{1280}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aspectratio}{4/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\screenwidth}{(\diagonal*\aspectratio)/sqrt(\aspectratio^2+1)}
\begin{document}
    \screenwidth
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the result is `1024.0023`, so it is not absolutely accurate. If you need only the integer part of the result, you can use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\screenwidth}{(\diagonal*\aspectratio)/sqrt(\aspectratio^2+1)}` instead, which cuts off the decimal places.

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to compile with `lualatex`, you can let [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) do the calculations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\diagonal{1280}
\def\aspectratio{4/3}
\edef\screenwidth{\directlua{tex.print (\diagonal*\aspectratio/math.sqrt((\aspectratio)^2+1))}}

\show\screenwidth
\end{document}
```

gives

```
> \screenwidth=macro:
->1024.
```

Calculations performed by Lua are more precise then calculations with TeX lengths (i.e. what `calc` and `pgf` use).

Comment: true about accuracy with `calc` and `pgf`. The `fp` package will, however, give you better accuracy than Lua.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pgfmath` (`pgf` package) which gives you a `sqrt` function. However, like Harlad Hanche-Olsen already mentioned in his comment, it depends on the required accurate. This uses the precision of TeX length registers which has its limitations.

An example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\newlength{\lengtha}
\newlength{\lengthb}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\lengtha}{3pt}
\setlength{\lengthb}{5pt}

\pgfmathparse{sqrt(\lengtha*\lengtha + \lengthb*\lengthb)}
\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

One can use the `fp` module of LaTeX3:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\widthfromdiagonal}{mmmm}
  {
    \dim_set:Nn #4
      {
        \fp_to_dim:n
          { \dim_to_fp:n {#1} * (1 + ((#3) / (#2))^2)^-0.5 }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\widthfromdiagonal{13cm}{4}{3}{\textwidth}
```

The first argument is the length of the diagonal, the second and the third the aspect ratio, the fourth the dimension to set.

This will set the `\textwidth` parameter to `295.90866pt`. Doing backwards the calculation with `bc`, this corresponds to a 12.9999999cm diagonal.

Comment: Can you update your answer using the new fp?

Comment: I *don't* have the new fp and clairvoyance is not among my skills. :) Please, if you decide to modify the answer, keep also the old code.

Comment: sorry, I forgot that it isn't on CTAN yet.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Will the old syntax cease to work?

Comment: long-term, that's the plan.  I don't quite remember the deprecation date, but I think it should be somewhere around the end of the year.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [xintexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) package for expressions or its sub-component [xint and xintfrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) for using macros. These macros are expandable. Hence they can be used directly in length definitions or assignments to counters, etc..., naturally if the number does not exceed the `TeX` bounds. The macros by themselves deal with arbitrarily big integers or fractions or decimal numbers.

Update because my initial answer had a *very* strange way of computing a diagonal!!! I make a poor Pythagorian...

```
\documentclass [a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xint}

\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newlength\diagonal

\begin{document}

\setlength\diagonal {\xintiiSqrtR{\xintiiAdd{\xintiiSqr{\number\pdfpagewidth}}{\xintiiSqr{\number\pdfpageheight}}}sp}

From the length register defined via macros of \verb|xint| we get \the\diagonal.

We could have also used an expression inside the length definition, or
directly here without using a length we obtain directly \the\dimexpr
\xinttheiiexpr sqrtr(\pdfpagewidth^2+\pdfpageheight^2)\relax sp. This was
naturally rounded to integral number of scaled points, and used \TeX's own
conversion to points via \verb|\the|.

If we prefer to get the value in centimeters, here we go:
\xinttheiexpr [6] sqrt(\pdfpagewidth^2+\pdfpageheight^2)/65536/72.27*2.54\relax cm.

For people who want to check with their calculator, this is supposed to
correspond to the diagonal length of a rectangle with side lengths of
\xinttheiexpr [6]\pdfpagewidth/65536/72.27*2.54\relax cm and 
\xinttheiexpr [6]\pdfpageheight/65536/72.27*2.54\relax cm.
\end{document}
```

> [image: diagonal]

Comment: People needing repetitive conversions from a length register to its value in centimeters with `1/1000cm` of precision may use: `\xintNewIExpr \ToCms [1]{[4] 1/65536/72.27*2.54*protect(\number #1)}`. Then `\ToCms {\mylength}` or `\ToCms\mylength` does the conversion. Curious people will due `\meaning\ToCms` to see what it does (it does extra things not needed here but due to the fact that `xintexpr` allows comma separated things in general). Requires `\input xintexpr.sty` or `\usepackage{xintexpr}`. Or `\def\ToCms #1{\xintRound {4}{\xintMul {127/236814336[0]}{\number #1}}}` with only `xintfrac`