# Floating point calculations in LaTeX?

Tags: calculations

I am looking for a method to do minimal floating point / integer calculations in LaTeX, not for the purpose of package writing, but for the production of actual text.

Here is an example to illustrate. Given the following input text

```
 The experiment included running a battery of \bind{T}{21} tests
 on \bind{S}{13} subjects, for a total of \bind{V}{T*S} expected values.
 However, since \bind{F}{37} values were defective, our successful 
 measurement rate per subject was \use{100*round((V-F)/T,2)}\%
```

it would be nice if was converted to:

```
 The experiment included running a battery of $21$ tests
 on $13$ subjects, for a total of $273$ expected values.
 However, since $37$ values were defective, our successful 
 measurement rate per subject was $86$\%.
```

Where `\bind{C}{expression}` defines a new constant `C` whose value is `expression`, and returns `C`, while `\use{C}` simply returns the value of `C`.  Any tips?

I am aware of the `spreadtab` package and this question: [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/how-can-i-automatically-calculate-sums-in-a-latex-table), but I am looking for something more.

Comment: I smell a singleton pattern...

Comment: Maybe the answers to [this very related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15028/calculating-right-angle-triangle-side-inside-latex) can help you.

Comment: The [`calculator`](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/calculator/calculator.pdf) packages seems also indicated, since it's easy to implement, and works with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't mind using luatex, then you could just let lua do the calculations. I use ConTeXt, but I believe that the `luacode` package in LaTeX provides similar functionality.

```
\startusercode
  round = global.math.round 
\stopusercode

\def\bind#1#2%
    {\usercode{#1 = #2}\use{#1}}

\def\use#1%
    {\usercode{global.context(#1)}}

\starttext
 The experiment included running a battery of \bind{T}{21.0} tests
 on \bind{S}{13} subjects, for a total of \bind{V}{T*S} expected values.
 However, since \bind{F}{37} values were defective, our successful 
 measurement rate per subject was \use{100*round((V-F)/T,2)}\%
\stoptext
```

I am using `usercode` rather `luacode` so that my definitions (`T=21` etc) do not pollute the global namespace.

**EDIT**: If you want the result to be in math mode, change `global.context(...)` to `global.context.math(...)` in the definition of `\use`

Answer (score 18):

Another package to do floating point computations is `l3fp`.  This package does not (yet) allow users to define new variables (but it supports `pi`, for instance, so in principle it shouldn't be too hard to extend it to support user-defined variables).  A workaround is to go through the expression and replace all variables `T`, `V`, etc. by an internal variable `\l__my_T_fp`, `\l__my_V_fp`, etc., which holds the corresponding value.

This is done by the looping macro `\__my_use:N`, which reads one character at a time.  If it is the end-marker `\q_recursion_tail`, then we reached the end of the expression, so exit the loop by skipping to `\q_recursion_stop` (done by `\quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n`).  If the variable `\l__my_#1_fp` is defined, then use it, otherwise leave the character itself for the `l3fp` functions to receive.  Then recurse by calling `\__my_use:N` again.

The `\my_set:nn` function makes sure that `\l__my_#1_fp` is defined thanks to `\fp_zero_new:c`, then it sets its value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__my_use:N #1
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#1}
    \cs_if_exist_use:cF { l__my_#1_fp } {#1}
    \__my_use:N
  }
\cs_new:Npn \my_use:n #1
  { \fp_eval:n { \__my_use:N #1 \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_set:nn #1#2
  {
    \fp_zero_new:c { l__my_#1_fp }
    \fp_set:cn { l__my_#1_fp } { \my_use:n {#2} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand {\bind} { m m } { \my_set:nn {#1} {#2} \my_use:n {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand {\use} { m } { \my_use:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
 The experiment included running a battery of \bind{T}{21} tests
 on \bind{S}{13} subjects, for a total of \bind{V}{T*S} expected values.
 However, since \bind{F}{37} values were defective, our successful
 measurement rate per subject was \use{100*round((V-F)/V,2)}\%
\end{document}
```

I also fixed the last formula, which read `(V-F)/T`.

Answer (score 15):

I have been extensively using the `fp` for this type of work. Here is a minimal for some functions, that can convert temperature units from one system to another. There are a lot of examples on this site that use the `fp` package. The code uses the `siunitx` package for formatting as well.

For example to translate degrees F to C you type `\Ftoc{32.999}`. Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\gdef\numdec{3}

\begin{document}
%\SetConversion{C}{K}{273.15}
\def\CtoK#1{\FPadd\result{#1}{273.15}%
\FPround\result{\result}{2}%
\sisetup{%
fixed-exponent = 2,
scientific-notation = false}
 \num{\result}}


%% Convert Centigrate to Fahreneit
\def\CtoF#1{\FPdiv\resulta{9}{5}%
\FPmul\resultb{\resulta}{#1}%
\FPadd\resultc{\resultb}{32}%
\FPround\resultc{\resultc}{3}%
 \num{\resultc}%
\sisetup{%
fixed-exponent = 0,
scientific-notation = false}
}

%% Convert Fahreneit to Centigrade
\def\FtoC#1{\FPdiv\resulta{5}{9}%
\FPsub\resultb{#1}{32}%
\FPmul\resultc{\resultb}{\resulta}%
\FPround\resultc{\resultc}{\numdec}%
\sisetup{%
fixed-exponent = 0,
scientific-notation = false}
\num{\resultc}%
}

%% Convert Fahreneit to Rankine
\def\FtoRa#1{\FPmul\result{#1}{9}%
\FPdiv\result{\result}{5}%
\FPround\result{\result}{\numdec}%
\result%
}

%% Convert Kelvin to Rankine
\def\KtoRa#1{\FPadd\result{#1}{459.67}%
\FPround\result{\result}{\numdec}\result}

%% Convert Rankine to Celcius
\def\RtoC#1{\FPsub\result{#1}{459.67}% to fahreneit
\FtoC{\result}}


\FtoC{32.999}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would use the math engine of `pgf` for it.

It would be much simpler if you would use macro names instead, e.g. `\T` instead of `T`.
Then `\bind` could be defined as `\newcommand\bind[2]{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}#1}` and `\use` would be `\newcommand\use[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}`. You would need to write `\use{100*round((\V-\F)/\T,2)}` then.

IMHO using characters only should be possible, but would requires the definition of the characters as PGF constants/functions. I not fully sure if this will work with your original syntax.

Comment: This will only work in the current scope, right?  Perhaps that's a good thing.  But I'm worried about cluttering the namespace with all those one-character control sequences.

Comment: In particular, you redefine `\S` in this example.

Comment: Yes, you need to be careful with the macro names. Added a prefix would be much saver. I just wanted to show the principle.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, this will only be working the current scope. Except if you use `\gdef` instead of `\def`.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It provides two LaTeX macros: `\bind` and `\use`. In addition, because Lua does not provided a built-in `round` function, it supplies an implementation of `round`, for use in a `\use` directive.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% The LaTeX macros "\bind" and "\use" invoke "\directlua{...}"
%% to perform their task(s).
\newcommand\bind[2]{\directlua{#1=#2;tex.sprint(#1)}}
\newcommand\use[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1)}}

%% Define two auxiliary functions: "round2int" and "round"
\directlua{%
   function round2int ( x )
      return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
   end
   function round ( num , digits )
      return round2int ( num * 10^digits ) / 10^digits
   end
}

\begin{document}
The experiment included running a battery of \bind{T}{21} tests on
\bind{S}{13} subjects, for a total of \bind{V}{T*S} expected values.
However, since \bind{F}{37} values were defective, our successful 
measurement rate per subject was \use{100*round((V-F)/V,2)}\%. More 
precisely, the successful measurement rate per subject was 
\use{100*round((V-F)/V,4)}\%.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I merged the two directives in one and use `siunitx`. Is there any warnings to do that ? : `\NewDocumentCommand{\CLua}{
 o % Affecte à une variable
 m % valeur ou calcul avec les variables définies
 o % unités pour siunitx
 }{%
 \IfValueT{#1}{\directlua{#1=#2}}%
 \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
  \num{\directlua{tex.sprint(#2)}}%
  }{%
  \SI{\directlua{tex.sprint(#2)}}{#3}%
 }%
}`

Comment: @Tarass - Believe it or not, but I'm absolutely no good at LaTeX3-syntax. I can't tell what your macro does. Sorry.

Comment: It's normal tex syntax. Never mind. Thank you.

Comment: @Tarass - Pardon me -- I should have written "I am unfamiliar with the `\NewDocumentCommand` syntax".

Comment: Thank you anyway, I'm very glad with your answer. I just asked you by precaution.

Answer (score 4):

Package [xintexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) allows exact computations on arbitrarily big numbers and fractions and decimal numbers, and it allows definition of variables (with no `\`) for use in later `\xintexpr`, `\xintfloatexpr` or `\xintiexpr`.

It works purely internally to `TeX`, building upon the `e-TeX` extension `\numexpr`. It can do floating point evaluations according to the value set by `\xintDigits:=N;`. Default is with `16` digits of precision.

This answer illustrates the use of user-declared variables, which was introduced with release `1.1` of `2014/10/28`. Thus, the implementation of `\bind` and `\use` is straightforward.

Allowed variable names are composed with letters, digits, underscores and are not allowed to start with a digit.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintexpr}% v1.1 or later

% If you use \bind with single letters T, S, etc...,
% they will not be allowed in dummy summations such
% as add(T^2, T=1..10) inside \xintexpr, \xintfloatexpr,... anymore.

% If \bind is used in an environment it obeys its scope and the
% remark above does not apply outside of the environment.

% This computes first argument as result of evaluation of second
% argument.
\newcommand*{\bind}[2]{\xintdefvar #1:=#2;\xinttheexpr #1\relax}

% The first argument specifies the number of digits
% to retain for fixed point output after decimal mark
% Default is 0, which means, round to nearest integer.
\newcommand*{\use}[2][0]{\xinttheiexpr [#1]#2\relax} 

\begin{document}
The experiment included running a battery of \bind{T}{21} tests
 on \bind{S}{13} subjects, for a total of \bind{V}{T*S} expected values.
 However, since \bind{F}{37} values were defective, our successful 
 measurement rate per subject was
% Note: the original has (V-F)/T which appears to be a misprint.
\use{100*(V-F)/V}\%.

More precisely the
 success rate per subject was \use[2]{100*(V-F)/V}\%.

Another experiment had  \bind{F}{53} defective values and its
success rate per subject was \use[2]{100*(V-F)/V}\%.

\end{document}
```

> [image: user declared xintexpr variables]

Answer (score 3):

An easy and intuitive solution is to use the package [`calculator`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calculator). It enables variables handling (definition, use and calculation) easily and *without* needing LuaTeX, nor eTeX.

To affect a value to a variable, you use `\COPY{<value>}{\myVariable}` (yes, it's upper case). You can then print/use your variable value as simply as `\myVariable`.

To do some calculation, you do `\ADD{<a>}{<b>}{<command_that_is_a+b>}` (the same with `\SUBTRACT`,`\MULTIPLY`,`\DIVIDE`... see [manual](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/calculator/calculator.pdf) p. 6 and after for more detail).

Below are shown three MWE that compute following output (twice the same sentence, with only a change in variables values):
[image: MWE]

- **MWE1**: Intuitive and easy to implement (but does not follow your syntax).
  ***=> good for those who want to do some floating point calculations in LaTeX***.
- **MWE2**: Implements the `\bind{<letter>}{<value>}` into MWE 1, which uses `TeX` macros (so less obvious to replicate for `LaTeX`-learners). It follows your syntax, except for the `\use`-command.
- **MWE3**: *[Work in progress]* Follows all your syntax.

---

### MWE1

This MWE *changes your syntax*. It is however easy to use and reuse, since it only loads a `LaTeX`-package and used macro are explicit. This might thus be adequate for people who wants to do "floating point calculations in LaTeX".

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{calculator}
    \usepackage{xspace}% xspace "smartely" adds or not a space at the end of the macro

    \newcommand*{\printExpectedValue}{%
        \MULTIPLY{\myT}{\myS}{\myV}% compute "V" value
        \GLOBALCOPY{\myV}{\myV}% makes "V" a global constant: needed to compute SucessfulRate
        $\myV$\xspace% print "V" in mathmode
    }

    \newcommand*{\printSucessfulRate}{%
        \SUBTRACT{\myV}{\myF}{\intermediateResultA}% does the intermediary calculation
        \DIVIDE{\intermediateResultA}{\myV}{\intermediateResultB}%
        \MULTIPLY{\intermediateResultB}{100}{\intermediateResultC}%
        \ROUND[0]{\intermediateResultC}{\mySucessfulRate}%
        $\mySucessfulRate$\%\xspace% prints result in math-mode
    }

\begin{document}
    \COPY{21}{\myT}% defines \myT
    \COPY{13}{\myS}% defines \myS
    \COPY{37}{\myF}% defines \myF
    The first experiment included running a battery of $\myT$ tests on $\myS$ subjects, for a total of \printExpectedValue expected values.
    However, since $\myF$ values were defective, our successful measurement rate per subject was \printSucessfulRate.

    \COPY{42}{\myT}% redefines \myT
    \COPY{17}{\myS}% redefines \myT
    \COPY{210}{\myF}% redefines \myT
    The second experiment included running a battery of $\myT$ tests on $\myS$ subjects, for a total of \printExpectedValue expected values.
    However, since $\myF$ values were defective, our successful measurement rate per subject was \printSucessfulRate.
\end{document}
```

---

### MWE2

This MWE replicates the `\bind{<letter>}{<value>}` command. However, it therefor uses plain-TeX commands, which might be not indicated if you don't know what you are doing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{calculator}
    \usepackage{xspace}% xspace "smartely" adds or not a space at the end of the macro

    \newcommand*{\bind}[2]{%
        \expandafter\def\csname my#1\endcsname{#2}% defines the \myX macro
        $#2$\xspace%\prints the "X" value in math-mode
    }

    \newcommand*{\printExpectedValue}{%
        \MULTIPLY{\myT}{\myS}{\myV}% compute "V" value
        \GLOBALCOPY{\myV}{\myV}% makes "V" a global constant: needed to compute SucessfulRate
        $\myV$\xspace% print "V" in mathmode
    }

    \newcommand*{\printSucessfulRate}{%
        \SUBTRACT{\myV}{\myF}{\intermediateResultA}% does the intermediary calculation
        \DIVIDE{\intermediateResultA}{\myV}{\intermediateResultB}%
        \MULTIPLY{\intermediateResultB}{100}{\intermediateResultC}%
        \ROUND[0]{\intermediateResultC}{\mySucessfulRate}%
        $\mySucessfulRate$\%\xspace% prints result in math-mode
    }
\begin{document}
    The first experiment included running a battery of \bind{T}{21} tests on \bind{S}{13} subjects, for a total of \printExpectedValue expected values.
    However, since \bind{F}{37} values were defective, our successful measurement rate per subject was \printSucessfulRate.

    The second experiment included running a battery of \bind{T}{42} tests on \bind{S}{17} subjects, for a total of \printExpectedValue expected values.
    However, since \bind{F}{210} values were defective, our successful measurement rate per subject was \printSucessfulRate.
\end{document}
```

---

### MWE3

Still struggling with it. Any help is welcome `(-;`