# Storing and manipulating real numbers

Tags: calculations

Is there any way to store real numbers (e.g. `4.5`) as variable / macro / counter / whatever in standard LaTeX (no direct Lua code) and perform the 4 basic mathematical operations with them? I need to be able to store such numbers and perform repeated calculations on them, at different points in my code (not just once).

I've considered storing the numbers as lengths (say multiplied by `100pt`) but I am stuck at recovering the underlying numbers (to actually use them to multiply other lengths...).

Bonus point if you minimize the number of external packages required. As for everything TeX, I am pretty sure someone will come up with a way to do this with `tikz` :)

Comment: There are various solutions depending on the detail of your requirements. Assuming e-TeX and 'simple' calculations, using dimensions and stripping off the `pt` is probably 'lowest' cost (no packages). On the other hand, clearer solutions involving either `fp`, `pgfmath` or the expandable `l3fp` are all also available.

Comment: You might want to look at for example [Floating point calculations in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15526)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the link! I searched a bit but hadn't seen that question. Please feel free to close mine as a duplicate. Ah, and there _is_ some `pgf` / `tikz` answer :)

Comment: I just discovered another option for simple calculations: use lenghts and the `\real` and `\ratio` macros of the `calc` package.