# How to sum coordinates in a \put command in Latex

Tags: coordinates

I would like to place a series of lines using the picture environment in latex but I can to placement of those lines to be relatively placed not absolutely place; i.e. I want to have defined coordinates that I can build off of.

Basic example of absolute placement:

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.75mm}
\begin{picture}(60,40)
\put(20,20){\line(5,2){1}}
\put(30,20){\line(5,3){1}}
\end{picture}
```

Basic example of relative placement (what I would like):

```
xc=20

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.75mm}
\begin{picture}(60,40)
\put(xc,20){\line(5,2){1}}
\put(xc+10,20){\line(5,3){1}}
\end{picture}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can consider performing (expandable) floating point operations. Here's a start: [Floating point calculations in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15526/5764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\xc{20}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}%.75mm is rather small

\fbox{\begin{picture}(60,40)
\put(\xc,20){\line(5,2){10}}% 1 mm is too small
\put(\numexpr\xc+10\relax,20){\line(5,3){10}}
\end{picture}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow quite extensive syntax but might be overkill.

I am assuming only integer calculations are needed (hence the `ii`) as in `\numexpr`. Use `/` for usual rounded integer division. Use `//` for floored division and `/:` for associated modulo. You can also use comma separated expressions (but `\put` must see the comma first, sadly, it can not arise from expansion alone thus I can't demonstrate it in this example). The syntax admits powers, factorials, ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintexpr}
\newcommand\IntExpr[1]{\xinttheiiexpr #1\relax}
\begin{document}

\xintdefiivar xc:=20;%

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.75mm}

\begin{picture}(60,40)
\put(\IntExpr{xc},20){\line(5,2){10}}
\put(\IntExpr{xc+10},20){\line(5,3){10}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in languages makeing the `:` or `;`active like babel+frenchb, one needs to turn this off for `\xintdefiivar`, or alternative is to define a wrapper for it in preamble where the `:` and `;`  still have their usual catcodes.