# How do I comment a single line?

Tags: comments

Too many search results for commenting multiple lines, because apparently that's hard to do.

I'm interested in commenting a single line.

Example:

```
%COMMENT% I learned about \numexpr at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422227/140752
\put(\numexpr1+1,-3){\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{pdfs/1.pdf}}}
```

What should I put at `%COMMENT%`?

Comment: Do you want the comment to show up in the actual output? Or just as part of your LaTeX code? If it's the latter, then starting the line with `%` is sufficient (you're already doing that).

Comment: Perfect, thank you