# Adding to number

Tags: tex-core, calculations

I want to check if the value of the parameter is negative.  If the parameter is negative, I want to substract 0.5 and if it is positive, I want to add 0.5.

The best I could do is define new variable like this

```
\ifnum#1<0 \def\xa{#1-0.5} \else \def\xa{#1+0.5}\fi
```

but this does not work.  Is this possible to do in plan tex/latex without external library?

**EDIT**: Since #1 is fortunately integer, this works `\def\xa{#1.5}`.  However, what if I wanted to add `1.5`?

Comment: `\ifnum` (and things like `\numexpr`) only deal in integers; `\def` does not perform arithmetic.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Fortunately, #1 is integer.

Comment: In what sense “it doesn't work”?

Comment: @egreg If `#1` is `-5`, then  `\xa` is not `-5.5`

Comment: @Pygmalion TeX doesn't directly support arithmetic on floating point numbers. What's your aim?

Comment: If `#1` is an integer, all you need is to append `.5` to `\xa` regardless of the sign.

Comment: @ABC Yes I figured that out, see EDIT.

Comment: @egreg if this is not doable, maybe I should simply close the question?

Comment: Are you interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: What should be done if the integer-valued parameter is equal to 0?

Comment: Mostly duplicate of [Floating point calculations in LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/floating-point-calculations-in-latex#comments-15529) but there's a simpler way in this question. (append the string  `.5`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Found it would be too long to fit for a comment so I post this one)

To add a general number possibly with decimals, you will nee

1. append `pt` to each number
2. use `\the\dimexpr` to do calculations, and get back a dimension
3. define a macro to strip the trailing `pt`, e.g. [`\pgf@sys@tonumber`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/80c4ebfb4472a550fa05d9f6f7514dfeb8bb9150/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex#L28-30) in `pgf` and [`\strip@pt`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/a9385d0d090b7e4fe4ce762798affb6f6e854642/base/ltfssbas.dtx#L1025-L1031) in latex2e.

```tex
% pgf, pgfsys.code.tex
{\catcode`\p=12\catcode`\t=12\gdef\Pgf@geT#1pt{#1}}

\def\pgf@sys@tonumber#1{\expandafter\Pgf@geT\the#1}

% latex2e, ltfssbas.dtx
% bonus: this also simplify 1.0pt to 1, not 1.0
\begingroup
  \catcode`P=12
  \catcode`T=12
  \lowercase{
    \def\x{\def\rem@pt##1.##2PT{##1\ifnum##2>\z@.##2\fi}}}
  \expandafter\endgroup\x
\def\strip@pt{\expandafter\rem@pt\the}
```

Combining all these,

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addnum}[2]{\expandafter\strip@pt\dimexpr#2pt+#1pt\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\addnum{1}{1.3}
\addnum{1}{-1.3}
\end{document}
```

output

> 2.3 -0.3

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment. As mentioned in the comment for the original question you only need to append `.5` to `\xa`. For the extended question, you can work with `\the\numexpr` which allows you to add integers. (If you wanted to add non-integers you could work with dimensions but presumably it makes more sense to employ `xfp` in that case.) The macro `\mytest` refers to the original question, `\anothertest` to the case in which you want to add/subtract `1.5`, and `\generaltest` allows you to shift by general integers, which is the optional parameter the default of which is `1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\edef\xa{#1.5}}
\newcommand{\anothertest}[1]{\ifnum#1<0\relax
 \edef\xa{\the\numexpr#1-1}%
\else 
 \edef\xa{\the\numexpr#1+1}%
\fi
\edef\xa{\xa.5}}
\newcommand{\generaltest}[2][1]{\ifnum#2<0\relax
 \edef\xa{\the\numexpr#2-#1}%
\else 
 \edef\xa{\the\numexpr#2+#1}%
\fi
\edef\xa{\xa.5}}
\begin{document}
\mytest{2}\xa

\mytest{-4}\xa

\anothertest{2}\xa

\anothertest{-4}\xa

\generaltest[1]{2}\xa

\generaltest[1]{-4}\xa

\generaltest[2]{2}\xa

\generaltest[6]{-4}\xa

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that mainly that you're working with decimals. The typical way of working with decimals in (La)TeX is to treat them like dimensions. So, instead of `2.5` (say), use `2.5pt`. However, this approach is a bit cumbersome.

You can rely on the ternary operator of [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) that evaluates a `condition` and branches to evaluate either `true` or `false`, depending on the `condition`. Specifically, it has the following format:

> condition ? true : false

Since `\fpeval` (for `f`loating `p`oint operations) is expandable, you can use it to define some macro based on the calculation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\addnum}[1]{%
  %                <cond> ?  <true>  :  <false>
  \edef\xa{\fpeval{#1 < 0 ? #1 - 0.5 : #1 + 0.5}}%
}

\begin{document}

\addnum{2}$\xa$% 2 + 0.5 = 2.5

\addnum{-1}$\xa$% -1 - 0.5 = -1.5

\addnum{3.141}$\xa$% 3.141 + 0.5 = 3.641

\addnum{-2.718}$\xa$% -2.718 - 0.5 = -3.218

\end{document}
```