# Calculate a floating point value to scale a length

Tags: calculations, lengths

As background, I was trying to write a macro that divides a page into columns given just a decimal scale factor. For example, given an input of .7 it should create columns of width .7*\textwidth and .3*\textwidth. Basically, I want to calculate `(1-#1)*\textwidth`.

It doesn't seem to be possible to use floating point values with \numexpr and \dimexpr, for example `\dimexpr\textwidth*(1-#1)` or `\dimexpr\numexpr(1-#1)\textwidth`. In this case there is a workaround, which is `\dimexpr\textwidth-#1\textwidth`. But it's easy to see how this would not work for more complex calculations.

Is there a way to do his using only (e)(La)TeX features? If not, what is the best alternative? [Floating point calculations in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/floating-point-calculations-in-latex) gives some packages for floating point calculations but doesn't deal with lengths.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of importing a couple of expl3 kernel commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpeval}{m}{\fp_eval:n{#1}}
\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand{\dimeval}{m}{\dim_eval:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\testlena} % for testing
\newlength{\testlenb} % for testing

\newcommand{\process}[1]{%
  \setlength{\testlena}{\fpeval{#1}\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\testlenb}{\fpeval{1-#1}\textwidth}%
}

\begin{document}

\process{0.7}
\the\testlena\ --- \the\testlenb

\process{0.5}
\the\testlena\ --- \the\testlenb

\process{2^(-3)}
\the\testlena\ --- \the\testlenb

\setlength{\testlena}{\dimeval{(\textwidth+\textheight)/2}}
\the\testlena

\end{document}
```

For your application you just need `\fpeval`, but I showed also an example for `\dimeval`.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, and no extra packages needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing the question I found at least one possible solution using the package `xintexpr`:

`\xinttheexpr(1-#1)\relax\textwidth`

`\relax` is needed to terminate `\xinttheexpr` even though it wouldn't be needed for `\numexpr` in this context. It's not clear to me why `\xinttheexpr` must be used rather than the simpler `\xintexpr`.