# Is there a basic float number type in LaTeX?

Tags: counters, lengths, number, count

I've tried some examples with counters and numbers in LaTeX. I create a counter with `\newcounter`. I understand that it declares an integer. So if we make like this

```
\newcounter{num}
\setcounter{num}{10}
\divide\value{num} by 4\relax
\thenum
```

the result will be 2. It is an integer division (div) and the fractional part of the result is being neglected. Is there an opportunity to get `2.5` as a result in the example above? Maybe here we must define not a counter but a kind of float number? I also tried `\newcount` but the result is the same. Well, a count is an integer... Also I tried an example with `\newlength`:

```
\newlength\x
\setlength{\x}{10cm}
\divide\x by 4\relax
\the\x
```

The result is in pt's and if to convert it to cm's it would be about 2.5 cm. But I don't need lengths -- I am interested in just numbers. So how to define a float number and perform basic operations with it? Can we achieve this without using extra packages but with basic TeX/LaTeX capabilities?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with a *counter* variable that isn't integer-valued?

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: `\fpeval{10/4}` will give 2.5. Or `\newcommand\mynumber{10}\edef\mynumber{\fpeval{\mynumber/4}} \mynumber` (there are also fp-variables in the expl3-layer.)

Comment: @Mico well, I don't have a particular purpose with it. I am trying to understand the counters in LaTeX. I've read a counter is an integer. I wrote some examples and found out that the fractional part is not saved. So I thought is there a way to define not only an integer but a float. For example, it can be used to calculate a coefficient of a length or just print it in a text. (No, I don't use LuaLaTeX, unfortunately)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, I've tried the examples, they both gave 2.5. So am I right there is no basic command like '\newcounter' but for float numbers?

Comment: tex has no floating point, but as Ulrike says, latex provides `\fpeval`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and am I right TeX has no floating point because it was originally designed like that to make it work the same on different computers (not to use calculations with a floating point to avoid errors)?

Comment: yes implementations are allowed to use floating point in glue stretching, but not where the result is accessable from tex. (you can not see, from tex how much an `\hfill` stretches) all tex length calculations are integer calculation in `sp` units and just use decimal `pt` value for display

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/floating-point-calculations-in-latex