# Something like ebooktex?

Tags: linux, ebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use LaTeX to produce Epub](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub)

Can we generate an ebook in the free open standard EPUB or EPUB-3 directly from LaTeX?

I'm using Kile on a Linux system.

--

Please refer to:

[Use LaTeX to produce Epub](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub)

Comment: Hi Dr Beco `:)`. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub) is what are you looking?

Comment: Also related: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/effort-to-make-latex-ebook-friendly), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/latex-document-to-epub-or-mobi-ebook-formats-with-mathematical-formulas), [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/preparing-pdf-files-for-ebook-readers-etc)

Comment: hi @egreg, altough "related", I think reference "3" is misleading, as it is for preparing PDF, not EPUB. The others might have something to add.

Comment: @DrBeco The question m0nhawk linked to looks pretty much the same as yours, which would indicate that this question here should be closed as a duplicate. If you think it's not a duplicate, please edit your question to show clearly what you're asking that's not covered by the other question.

Comment: Hi @doncherry, I think the question is in the same line, yes. Better to close this one, and put the efforts to the older one. Thanks!

Comment: ALso it is possible to use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). It supports LaTeX-to-whatever conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Method was [reported](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/latex-lyx-e-books.html). Though it uses HTML as transitional format.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I don't want to "convert" some format (pdf for instance) to epub using calibre. This gives poor results.