# LaTeX options for kindle?

Tags: pdf, ebook, kindle

I was wondering if there are any good settings to produce a PDF suitable for 
reading on a (6 inch) kindle. Main use is for intermediate reading of academic papers while they are being written:

1. Text needs to be large enough to be readable.
2. Equations need to be readable.
3. I don't care much what happens to the figures. They may appear on a separate page

I prefer a solution with 3 files for every project, one which contains the text and equations (paper), one which compiles to standard format, and one which compiles to
kindle friendly format.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this is not a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/latex-options-for-kindle : I just need a way to format an article for intermediate reading

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the differences. That question had basically the same title. I changed it now to be more specific.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

## Here's a plan:

Create a `kindle-friendly` preamble (or a document class)

- Redefine your page geometry to match your screen ratio (`geometry` package)
- Remove most of the margins (also with `geometry`)
- Remove or resize headers and footers (perhaps with `fancyhdr`)
- Enlarge text until it is readable to you (*depends on which TeX friend you are using*)
- Choose appropriate (legible) fonts (*depends on which TeX friend you are using*)
- Redefine you section titles to smaller spacing (`titlesec` package)
- Reduce other spacing as well (*various lenghts like `\abovecaptionskip`*)

Don't use absolute sizes in your documents:

- Rescale your figures to fit `factor\textwidth`
- Mathematics should automatically break at the end of the line (`breqn` package *might* help)

If you didn't create a document class:

- Extract your document content (textbody) to a `content-file`
- `\include{content-file}` after the `\begin{document}`

If you created a document class, you will just have to change your class before compiling.

### Possible result

[image: Kindle pdf result]

The figure is the result of the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}      % font selection
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\usepackage{breqn}         % automatic equation breaking
\usepackage{microtype}     % microtypography, reduces hyphenation
\usepackage{polyglossia}   % language selection
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{graphicx}      % graphics support

\usepackage[font=small,labelformat=simple,]{caption}   % customizing captions

\usepackage{titlesec}      % customizing section titles
\titleformat{\section}{\itshape\large}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{8pt}{4pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\itshape}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{4pt}{2pt}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bf\scshape}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{5pt}{5pt}

\usepackage[papersize={3.6in,4.8in},hmargin=0.1in,vmargin={0.1in,0.1in}]{geometry}  % page geometry

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}            % clear page header
\fancyfoot{}            % clear page footer

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2pt} % space above captions 
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt} % space below captions
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{2pt}     % space between last top float or first bottom float and the text
\setlength{\floatsep}{2pt}         % space left between floats
\setlength{\intextsep}{2pt}        % space left on top and bottom of an in-text float

\begin{document}

In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.

\section{Wonderful section title}

Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had plenty of time as she went down to look 
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{alice}
\caption{Quite wide picture, resized to fit}
\end{figure}
about her and to wonder what was going to happen next.

\subsection{Tufte-style subsection}

then she looked at the sides of the well

\subsubsection{Saving space running in} and noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book\-shel\-ves. 

\begin{dmath}[label={sna74}]
\frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(k,h,0) +\frac{3(h-1)}{h}\right)
+\frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(h,k,0) +\frac{3(k-1)}{k}\right)
=\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{h}{k} +\frac{k}{h} +\frac{1}{hk}\right)
+\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2h} -\frac{1}{2k},
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Different font sizes can be easily selected using fontspec.

Comment: Last step: don’t forget to document and release your document class on CTAN.

Comment: Will this work with math typesetting?

Comment: @willem: I added using `breqn` package for automatic line breaking in math typesetting to the answer.

Comment: This allmost works (when translating some things to PDFLatex), but I'm having trouble also resizing Sections (\section, \subsection, \subsubsection)

Comment: @willem: You might try `titlesec` package.

Comment: This is also a good read: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=107585

Comment: @ipavlic silly question, but this presumably doesn't produce reflow-able text. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @snim2 If there is, I don't know of such a way. As far as I know, postscript and pdf are absolutely positioned documents, best suited for printing. Latex is a system that makes fine adjustments at "compile time" to produce beautifully positioned (typeset) document elements for the required output. Short of having a latex distribution of some sort on your e-reader, I don't really see how that might work. It would be something of a square peg in a round hole to do so anyway -- most e-readers have nice e-reading software that reads a suitable format (often xml-backed) and reflows it nicely.

Comment: @ipavlic I guess the only way then is to go though an HTML pass, as some other questions have hinted. Hmm.

Comment: @snim2 Now that I think of it again, it seems to me that I was watching a lecture on some conference about having latex documents as images in a couple of sizes to fake re-flowing or something like that. I can't remember where I've seen it though. The lecturer was an engineer of some sorts, had to ask for permission from his company to fly to the conference, older fellow, TeX user. Maybe some other users can remember the lecture better.

Comment: @snim2: Currently not with LaTeX. See [How to create tagged PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579)

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! For my purpose, [I added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750239/3383640) a redefinition of the equation environment to scale the line down if necessary.

Answer (score 15):

While [ipavlic's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16737/5764) works more than fine, what is below does not require `fontspec` and `breqn` and is somewhat more minimalistic. Based on  [this thread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=107585), with a few tweaks that improve it's working with formulas (in my opinion). Very long formulas still partly disappear, and it does not work with tables. Figures are fine though, as long as they are included using relative width as in ipavlic's answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[papersize={108mm,144mm},margin=2mm]{geometry}  
\sloppy 
\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Answer (score 8):

I created some files for my Sony ebook reader. My final solution was to actually create ebooks from these papers. While it is possible from PDF - equations typically didn't survive this process.

The solution with best results for me was to create the document as HTML (can be done with [latex2html](http://biosun1.harvard.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/latex2html_creating_html_fr.html)) with the equations and figures as PNG files. This converts nicely.

As converter from HTML to ebook I used [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/).

Both utilities have a command line interface and could be put in your `makefile`.

Thinking about the kindle - maybe it is also possible to upload the HTML directly. Also I'm not sure - maybe it also supports [MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/) - which might lead to even nicer looking equations.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) to convert your LaTeX to EPUB. This would be reflowable, and would work on different sized readers without adjustment. Equations are handled quite nicely.

Comment: Have you tried this? From my past experience, Pandoc does not do well converting from LaTeX (for example, it would discard figures and captions). I don't think it handled custom definitions either. Hopefully it has improved?

Comment: I've converted LaTeX to EPUB, although it's not something I do a lot. You're right that figures are tricky. I'd be very interested in a neat solution to the problem. This filter might be a start: https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/blob/master/examples/tikz.py (I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 4):

Not yet mentioned here: [tex4ebook](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook):

from the command line:

```
tex4ebook [options] filename
```

You don't have to modify your source files unless you want to use commands defined by `tex4ebook` in the document.

If you want to use `tex4ebook` commands, add this line to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
```

but it is optional. There's no need to modify your TeX files.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
I use Xelatex compilator.
And I upload my .pdf to Amazon KDP.
My margins were too big.
The result was hardly readable at Kindle format/size.

I highly recommand to test the replacement of

```
\documentclass[ebook,13pt,a5paper]{book}
```

by

```
\documentclass[ebook,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

It solved my problem.
Regards
Olivier

Answer (score 2):

Main advises:

- Use `a6paper` in `geometry` option list, this may be the *designed* paper size for 6 inch Kindle.
- Remove all header/foot utils, they just waste spaces for the 6 inch kindle.
- Use relative width value for **all** width settings, especially environment related, i.e., for `Figure`, use `.9/textwidth` is a good trying, and you may find let this constant setting in your new environment is a good tip.
- For code environment, I recommend use `\begin{lstlisting}`, and you can use `\lstset` to customise it, and set `breaklines=ture` is another good tip.
- For tables, do not make over 3 columns, or you can rotate the table and change to use `longtable` if need.
- Add a new tag in your Makefile to create Kindle edition as long as the PC edition.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the template that I use. I generate both an A4 sized document and a 'Kindle sized' one when I compile my document. I've got some macros in there for reformatting columns and margin paragraphs in there too: https://github.com/Todd-Davies/latex-template

I also wrote a blog post on it a while ago (now slightly out of date):  http://todd-davies.github.io/2014/01/08/latex-and-the-kindle/