# Automatically breaking formulas

Tags: equations, line-breaking, ebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split an equation over two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines)

I am trying to compile my papers into Kindle readable PDF files. I can get pretty good outputs by just changing the height and the width of the document. One problem is formulas run out of the page and I cannot really adjust them manually for hundreds of formulas. I am wondering if there is any package that automatically breaks a formula if it runs out of the page margins.

Comment: You may want to look at [latex options for kindle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/latex-options-for-kindle), if you have not already seen it.

Comment: Perhaps try the `breqn` package? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578127/how-do-i-break-a-long-equation-over-lines/1581170#1581170) I haven't used it myself, but I think automatically breaking long formulas is one of its goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`breqn` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) does exactly this. You will have to modify your `equation` environments to `dmath` (or another) though. The [package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) describes this in detail under sections **9 Environments and commands** and **10 Various environment options**.