# Best solutions for (La)TeX on Kindle

Tags: compiling, online, kindle

I have read [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online), [LaTeX options for kindle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/latex-options-for-kindle), and some similar Q&A's, but I have more specific question.

What are possible, good solutions for compiling TeX/LaTeX documents from Kindle (3G)? Probably it should be done online. However, Kindle has got some limitations (e.g. bad keyboard, limitations on extensions of loadable files). So which page should be chosen? Or maybe there exists another solution?

**Edit** (2013-04-08 00:05 CET)
An existing answer gives only general ideas. I hope that there are people with some experience in using mobile devices to TeX & Co. exercises.

Comment: It's not really clear, you want to enter TeX file **on** Kindle, than somehow compile it (via online compiler like [ShareLaTex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project) and then get `.pdf` back to Kindle? I don't think this is possible, but would be happy to know I'm wrong.

Comment: @m0nhawk I am afraid that compiling on Kindle is impossible. I hope that there are  web pages, where I can compile, change extension and download the result onto Kindle.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke older kindle devices are based on linux, now they are using android I think. kindle 3g is linux based and it should be possible to get root access and install new programs. so at least theoretically, it should be possible. but I don't have kindle to test it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this](http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/latex.php) online compiler, the only strict problem I had was the Kindle's refusal to open PDFs online, as you found. It would be fairly simple for someone running a similar site to automate sending an email with the PDF as attachment rather than linking to the attachment direct, and you can set up your Amazon account to deliver PDF attachments to the Kindle. I don't know much about the way Kindles are set up, but if it were possible to bypass that restriction (which, given that Kindles can handle PDFs, and can download other types of files, feels like it should be possible) that would fit the bill.

Having said that, even the almost negligible amount of code I wrote on that site on my Kindle was incredibly laborious; I used my Kindle for internet for several weeks when my laptop broke a few years ago, but the quantity of backslashes and curly brackets needed for LaTeX make Kindles singularly unsuited to the job, in my opinion. Even if you were only editing documents the amount of time it takes to scroll up and down would be maddening.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am trying to obtain here any piece of information, how to deal with Kindle's restrictions and how to make usage of Kindle for  purposes of this side less maddening.